# Launch config does not recognize asset folder/assets not in jar

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I tried the new libgdx setup ui to experiment with Gradle. I have the following problems:

- If I create a run configuraiton in intellij for the desktop application it cannot be launched because the asset folder is not recognized. But if I run the "run" task in the dekstop build.gradle I can successfully launch the demo app.
- If I execute the "jar" task in the dekstop build.gradle I get a jar with only the main class. It seems that the core part is not included. Same happens if I launch the "jar" task from the main build.gradle.

What I did:

- I launched the setup ui and generated the files
- I imported the project in in intellij with Import Project and selected the main build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar task has a bug in the gradle script. It must be

```
from files(project.ext.assetsDir);
```

instead of

```
from files(project.assetsDir); //see the missing ext
```

The launchconfig needs the working directory set to "android/assets" because the demo project loads the file via the file api and not via classloader.